# How can I add additional arguments to a python code?

Tags: inheritance, python-2.7, arguments, argparse

I am using a python class which uses `argv` as a parameter to parse arguments given to the command line. What kind of parser this class is using I do not know, and I am not able to change this class anyway.

Now I want to create a new class, derived from the mentioned class, having additional arguments added with `argparse`. How can I achieve this in the most simple, reliable and pythonic way with `argparse`, with keeping the functionality of the original class intact and with a 'combined' help output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) method should be helpful for picking out your extra arguments; you can then replace `sys.argv` with its second output of the remaining argument string and pass control along.

Combined help output is going to be harder if you have no idea what parser it's using or any access to it. The best option I can think of is running the program with `--help` or whatever one time, saving the output as a string, and then adding that to the [`description`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#description) or [`epilog`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#epilog). Depending on how the code works, you could maybe automate this process with something along the lines of

```
import argparse
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

old_stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = cap = StringIO()
old_argv = sys.argv
sys.argv = ['--help']
TheClass().parse_args()
sys.stderr = old_stderr
sys.argv = old_argv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=cap.read())
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=float)

my_args, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()
sys.argv = remainder

TheClass(foo=my_args.foo).parse_args()
```

(Untested code, buyer beware.)

This is fairly likely to give you two initial usage lines, the first one listing your arguments and the second one the inner class's arguments. You can customize `argparse`'s line there with the [`usage`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#usage) argument, but it's still probably going to look a little weird; I don't know how to avoid that without manually editing the string.

Comment: Your comment does not 'completely' answer my question, but you mentioned enough bits and pieces I can build upon. Therefore I will accept the answer as 'correct'.